# How do I diagnose simple main.tf Terraform/AWS error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working from an Orielly Terraform book [newbie], and the first exercise of main.tf is:

```
provider "aws"  {
    region = "us-east-1"
}
```

`terraform plan` command generated the following error:

> **A default (non-aliased) provider configuration for "aws" was already given at main-code.tf:1,1-15...**

Searching got me nowhere as the problem may be either too simple or too weird.  I have provided AWS_KEYs... as exports in zsh, and my general aws cli queries work fine on this machine.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you put multiple `provider "aws"` in tf files. Delete duplicated provider should fix your issue.

Reference: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/configs/module.go#L143-L149

```
        if existing.Alias == "" {
            diags = append(diags, &hcl.Diagnostic{
                Severity: hcl.DiagError,
                Summary:  "Duplicate provider configuration",
                Detail:   fmt.Sprintf("A default (non-aliased) provider configuration for %q was already given at %s. If multiple configurations are required, set the \"alias\" argument for alternative configurations.", existing.Name, existing.DeclRange),
                Subject:  &pc.DeclRange,
            })
```